# Is memory usage doubled when using mmap on /dev/mem?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

My understanding of mmap is that when used on a file it essentially reserves space for that file in memory so that it's able to access it as fast as possible as soon as you need it. but what happens when you mmap a device like dev/mem where it IS the memory, does it then use some other memory to map that memory or is it smart enough to realize that it is mapping ram and doesn't need to store it in memory? What about if you map a RAM disk where it is still memory but it's not grouped in with the regular memory?

Comment: Learn the difference between memory and address space.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/mem` is the physical memory. It won't double your address space, it will add the amount of physical memory your machine has to your address space, but your actual memory usage will not go up.

Comment: ...until you actually start accessing it.

Comment: @TCvD: Nah. Some X output drivers work by mapping parts of `/dev/mem` into their address space so they can talk to video RAM.

Comment: @Joshua so it depends on the drivers implementation? If as you say, you're trying to map video memory, it won't occupy the same amount of space inside your system ram when you access it because the driver has specifically said to look at the VRAM directly instead?

Comment: @J.Doe: I don't think the driver implementing `/dev/mem` knows which RAM is video.